# Add CSS Class to element based on value length

Tags: javascript

I built a menu and when the menu item becomes too long I want to change some CSS. Here is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    var item1 = document.getElementByClass('nm-item-link-l');
    var item2 = document.getElementByClass('nm-item-link');
    if (item1.length > 20) {
        changeit = document.getElementByClass('nm-item-link-l').addClass('addclass');
    } else {
        ;
    }
    if (item2.length > 20) {
        changeit2 = document.getElementByClass('nm-item-link-l').addClass('addclass');
    } else {
        ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementByClass
```

is not a valid js function unless you've defined it yourself.  You possibly want `getElementByClassName`  Same for `addClass`. `addClass` is a valid jQuery method, but is not a standard javascript function.

#### Update based on comment

Since it seems you're using jQuery

```
   var list1 = $(".nm-item-link-l");
   var list2 = $(".nm-item-link");

   if (list1.length > 20) {
       list1.addClass("addClass");
   }
   if (list2.length > 20) {
       list2.addClass("addClass");
   }
```

#### Update #2,

Since it seems you want to filter by word length instead:

```
   var list1 = $(".nm-item-link-l");
   var list2 = $(".nm-item-link");
   list1.each(filterFunc);
   list2.each(filterFunc);

   function filterFunc(index,value){
     if (parseInt(value).text().length > 20) {
         $(value).addClass("addClass");
     }
   }
```

Comment: What if I do this 

var maxitemlength = 20;
$('.nm-item-link-l').filter(function() {
return $(this).text().length > maxitemlength;
}).addClass('addclass');

Comment: oh so you are yousing jQuery?

Comment: either way works fine. I tested all of the examples on this page and it doesn't work ...

Comment: @Artem you keep saying "doesn't work"  what do you mean by that.  What specifically happens or doesn't happen that you expect.  Are you seeing errors in the console?  If you're trying my example, did you import jQuery?

Comment: I used above jQuery script and when I set length to 6 everything is shows up, but when I change it to 7, it reads class and displays to 'none'. However, I have one word with 5 characters and 3 words width above 25 characters, and all of them go under same '6 & 7 rule' I described above.

Comment: The length in my selector is referring to the number of items you have with that class.  If you want to compare the lengths you'll need to do so for the individual items.  Why don't you revise your question to make your intentions more clear?

Comment: Right! Sorry about that. Yes, I need to add class only if menu items has more than 20 characters. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update. I tested and the rule gets affected only on first menu item. I have 7 (.nm-item-link-l) and 12 (.nm-item-link) menu items.

Comment: @Artem  All of this info really should have gone into your original question.  Without you doing that, helping you is trying to hit a moving target.  worth considering for next time

Comment: @Artem Should be fixed now.  If you have more issues please consider editing your question or opening a new question.  And try debugging yourself as well.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have no idea why your latest version doesn't work (nothing happens even when I change $(value).addClass("addclass"); to $(value).hide(); ) ... I have it after all items and everything looks fine ... I guess I have to open a new question.

Comment: @Artem  Have you looked to see if its throwing errors? There may be a syntax problem somewhere.  Don't give up so easily, try to figure out whats going on yourself first.

Comment: @Artem I took a second look, and I hadn't been grabbing the length anymore.  Its fixed now, but again, try to understand whats going on, don't just give up if something doesn't work, you won't learn anything

Comment: you are great ) I figured out that .length was missing and then saw you comment. In 'if (parseInt($(value).text().length,10) > 20) ' 10 means 10 menu items?

Comment: no you actually don't need the parseInt, I was trying something else.  The 10 argument is parseInt specifies that you want it in decimal notation rather than hexidecimal.  You don't need to worry about that though.  Just get the length.

Comment: Everything looks great and works the way it supposed to (but with 'if (parseInt($(value).text().length) > 20)'). IE7 freaked out a bit with next items, but I'll try to debug it myself. Thank again! It was super helpful and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here

1. `document.getElementByClass` should be `document.getElementsByClassName`
2. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of dom objects
3. There is no method called `addClass` in dom object, you need to use the property `className` to update the `class` attribute of an element.

Code

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('nm-item-link-l');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    items[i].className = 'addclass';
}
```

If you have jquery

```
var item1 = $('.nm-item-link-l');
if(item1.length > 20){
    item1.addClass('addclass')
}
```

Comment: `getElementByClass` doesn't exist :)

Comment: corrected, it was a copy paste mistake

Comment: Thank you all for all your answers. I added what you said and it doesn't work. To test I set class to have display:none and nothing happens. Maybe I should call this function first?

Comment: @ArunPJohny you still want elementsByClassName.  There can be multiple elements, which is part of what is confusing the OP I think.

Answer (score 0):

It is document.getElementsByClassName not document.getElementByClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
function minimumClass(nodes, className, minNodes) {
  for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; n > minNodes && i < n; i++) {
    nodes[i].classList.add(className);
  }
}

minimumClass(document.getElementsByClassName('nm-item-link-1'), 'add-class', 20);
minimumClass(document.getElementsByClassName('nm-item-link'), 'add-class', 20);
```

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the question. This answer adds a class to a list of elements if the class selector matches more than 20 elements. The question is apparently looking to add a class if one particular element has a value whose string length is longer than 20 characters.