# Centering an element when text is short, right align when text is long

Tags: html, css

As image, is it possible if the green element is aligned center when its needed width is shorter than parent width - yellow shape width, but align right if not? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Definitely possible with basic JavaScript. Can't think of a CSS only solution.

Comment: Left yellow block has a fixed width?

Comment: @Berzohr Yes, the bounds of yellow block is fixed.

Comment: You can define two different classes for text alignment on the basis of  text length. You can then assign relevant class. You can visit this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665273/add-css-class-to-element-based-on-value-length). Hope this will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without any library (e.g. Bootstrap), you could use a div with `display: table;` and `margin: 0 auto;`, nested with another div with `display: inline-block;` property.

This is the example:

```css
.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.yellowBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid #ffc107;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30px;
}

.pre-greenBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
}

.greenBlock {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="yellowBlock"></div>
  <div class="pre-greenBlock">
    <div class="greenBlock">Short text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="yellowBlock"></div>
  <div class="pre-greenBlock">
    <div class="greenBlock">Very looooooooooooooooooooooooong</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, you need control the width of your yellow and green block.

This isn't the unique solution. You could use too a table or Bootstrap with row and columns.